# PHP файл воспринимает -> как html комментарий

Tags: php, html, комментарии

Есть некий оператор ->, который позволяет использовать методы определенного класса. В php файле находится приблизительно следующий код:

```
<?php
    // Здесь идёт инициализация БД
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Шапка1</th>
            <th>Шапка2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $foo = Class->method; // Здесь идёт присвоение таблицы из бд переменной $foo, причем таблица передается как массив 
            foreach($foo as $element){
                $head1 = $element['head1'];
                $head2 = $element['head2'];
                echo "<tr><td>".$head1;
                echo "</td><td>".$head2;
                echo "</td></tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Вывод у этого следующий:

```
method; foreach($foo as $element){ $head1 = $element['head1']; $head2 = $element['head2']; echo ""; } ?>
```

А потом рисуется таблица, с шапкой, как надо, а содержимое - две ячейки на одной строке, содержание первой:

```
".$head1; echo "
```

... и второй:

```
".$head2; echo "
```

На сколько я понял, дело в операторе ->, который используется в html для комментирования, а в php для вызова методов класса. Как это пофиксить?

А, и если у кого-то возникнет желание посоветовать мне сделать через ajax запрос получение содержимого таблицы: не кнает, мне нужно именно так.

Comment: Каким образом? Приведите пример, пожалуйста

Comment: Что у вас находиться в `$element['head1']` и `$element['head2']` ?

Comment: Самые обычные строки

Comment: Судя по отрывку что вы указали, то проблема у вас в ковычках, где то не правильно выставлены, в итоге у вас текст не `<tr><td>` а `.$head1;
                echo `

Comment: Кавычки расставлены правильно, их чётное количество. И выводить он сначала начинает "method; foreach($foo as $element){ $head1 = $element['head1']; $head2 = $element['head2']; echo ""; } ?>", то есть проблема с выводом где-то до этого куска кода

Comment: Мне кажется, что ваш веб-сервер не обрабатывает PHP-код. Посмотрите исходный код страницы, которая генерируется.

Comment: Засунул ваш код в html файл, открыл в браузере. Отобразилось то же самое, что отображается у вас. Значит всё-таки PHP-код не выполняется.

Answer (score 1):

Php не воспринимает " -> как html комментарий", он знает что это, ну и как минимум в html это все же `<!-- -->`. Так и не понял в чем у вас там проблема, но в коде вы упустили закрывающийся тег `</td>`

```
echo "<tr><td>".$head1;
echo "</td><td>".$head2;
echo "</tr>";
```

Должно быть:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$head1;
echo "</td><td>".$head2."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Что бы не путаться в выводах и склейки строк, как пример:

```
<?php
    $foo = Class->method;
?>
<?php foreach($foo as $element){?>
    <tr>
        <td><php echo $element['head1'];?></td>
        <td><php echo $element['head1'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php} ?>
```

Comment: Знаю, я заметил и исправил это. Проблема в том, что оно выводит еще и method; foreach($foo as $element){ $head1 = $element['head1']; $head2 = $element['head2']; echo ""; } ?>, а не исполняет его

Comment: Вы так и пишите `Class->method` ? что такое `Class`?

Comment: Ну использование класса это `new ClassName()->methodName()` или `ClassName::methodName()` ну и другие варианты, что из этого в вашем коде?

Comment: $foo = NameSpace::$Instance->Method(args);
Поправочка, как оказалось, это не статический класс, а единственный существующий instance класса.

Comment: Не уверен конечно, но думаю что ваше статическое свойство `$Instance` может быть пустым. Может посмотрите в логи, на предмет ошибок.

Comment: Все работает, $instance тоже, он не пустой. В логах чисто

Comment: Я думаю, что я тогда неправильно выразился. html воспринял два символа из тегов <?php ?> как комментарий, а не php. Все, что было между <?php и -> не выполнилось, а все после -> вывелось на страницу